# Scala pattern matching option string

Tags: scala

I have an option of string called failureType. According to values of this String I have to decide what type of object I want to create. Something like -

```
val failure: Option[FailureType] = failureType map (f => f.toLowerCase match {
          case "build" => FailureType.BuildFailure
          case "test" => FailureType.TestFailure
          case "service timeout" => FailureType.ServiceTimeout
          case "job timeout" => FailureType.JobTimeout
          case "work item timeout" => FailureType.WorkItemTimeout
        } )
```

My problem is I get Match Error if I give values other than "build", "test", "service timeout", "job timeout" or "work item timeout" to failureType. Which makes sense because I am not doing any default catching.  So my problem is how to do this default catching ? If I do

```
case _ => None
```

At the end of other case statements, I would get error, because of course I am inside Map. My other option seem to be not using map at all and directly doing match -

```
val failure: Option[FailureType] = failureType match {
          case Some("build") => FailureType.BuildFailure
          case Some("test") => FailureType.TestFailure
          case Some("service timeout") => FailureType.ServiceTimeout
          case Some("job timeout") => FailureType.JobTimeout
          case Some("work item timeout") => FailureType.WorkItemTimeout
          case _ => None
        }
```

But in this case I lose the ability to do case insensitive matching.

Comment: Either you can `.filter` the `Option` to prevent unsupported value before the matching, or you `.flatMap[FailureType]` with `case _ => None` or you transform to another type which can represent a validation with predefined failure or unexpected one (maybe `Either[Option[String], SuccessType]` in your case).

Comment: Basically, collect function as other suggested. But why not have some generic error code? Are you sure it's OK to skip errors? You might end up with failing system, and you won't even know about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `.collect`:

```
val failure = failureType.map(_.toLowerCase).collect { 
   case "build" => FailureType.BuildFailure
   case "test" => FailureType.TestFailure
   case "service timeout" => FailureType.ServiceTimeout
   case "job timeout" => FailureType.JobTimeout
   case "work item timeout" => FailureType.WorkItemTimeout
}
```

`.collect` takes a `PartialFunction`, and will return the result of its application if the function is defined on the argument or `None` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `flatMap` - have the fall-through case return `None`, while the valid cases return `Some(_relevant_failure_type)`:

```
val failure: Option[FailureType] = failureType flatMap (f => f.toLowerCase match {
      case "build" => Some(FailureType.BuildFailure)
      case "test" => Some(FailureType.TestFailure)
      case "service timeout" => Some(FailureType.ServiceTimeout)
      case "job timeout" => Some(FailureType.JobTimeout)
      case "work item timeout" => Some(FailureType.WorkItemTimeout)
      case _ => None
    } )
```

Answer (score 3):

Part of the difficulty comes from trying to fold case and match at the same time. If you use `map (_.toLowerCase)` to fold the case first, you can use `collect` to do exactly what you want:

```scala
val failure: Option[FailureType] = failureType map (_.toLowerCase) collect {
  case "build" => FailureType.BuildFailure
  case "test" => FailureType.TestFailure
  case "service timeout" => FailureType.ServiceTimeout
  case "job timeout" => FailureType.JobTimeout
  case "work item timeout" => FailureType.WorkItemTimeout
}
```

The result will be `None` for any string not explicitly matched.